# how to convert cookie's GMT formated expires to float in Python http.cookiejar.Cookie method?

Tags: python, cookies

the cookie's expires returned by server is "Tue, 17-Oct-45 11:54:07 GMT",so when i try to set a cookie like this:

```
ID = Cookie(version=None,name='NAME',value='VALUE',port=None,port_specified=None,domain='.somedomain.com',domain_specified=None,domain_initial_dot=None,path='/',path_specified=None,secure=None,discard=None,comment=None,comment_url=None,rest=None,expires='Tue, 17-Oct-45 11:54:07 GMT')
```

and it raised a ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Tue, 17-Oct-45 11:54:07 GMT'

So, how to convert it?Thx in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# quick and easy way
from dateutil.parser import parse
from time import mktime

s = 'Tue, 17-Oct-45 11:54:07 GMT'
p = parse(s)
floating_number = mktime(p.timetuple())
```

Note if you do it this way, you are relying on dateutil's magic parser to guess the timestamp string right, and it usually is.

If you know the timestamp is always going to use the same format or a few formats, then just define the format per strptime formatting (http://strftime.org/) and use

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime

YOUR_FORMAT = """your format"""

date_string = 'Tue, 17-Oct-45 11:54:07 GMT'

# strip off the timezone here with split or regex, whatever you like

p = datetime.strptime(date_string, YOUR_FORMAT)
floating_number = mktime(p.timetuple())
```

if you do it that way, you'll also need to account for the timezone.  probably fine to just use dateutil